# Magento 2 file upload error

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, image, image-upload

I have upload customer image using ajax.I have upload images jpg,png,jpeg etc extension is working fine.But i have upload pdf extension showing below error

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Image.php on line 34
```

In database customer image attribute **`frontend_input`** is "image" value.

[image]

i have **`frontend_input`** change into "file" value pdf extension working fine.

So Plesae help.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code around the line specified in the error you will see why it doesn't work :)

```php
$allowImageTypes = ['gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
```

So basically, you can't upload a PDF and expect it to be treated as an image since this is not allowed file extension.